For which norms does closest projection never increase norm?
Let $X$ be a finite-dimensional normed space, and $V\subset X$ a vector subspace.
For a point $x\in X$ we define a closest projection of $x$ onto $V$ to be a minimizer $v^\star$ of $\|v-x\|$ amongst $v\in V$.
Under what conditions on the norm, can we guarantee that for all $V$ and $x$ there exist a projection $v^\star$ of $x$ onto $V$ for which furthermore there holds $\|v^\star\|\leq \|x\|$?
note based on comments It's obvious that $\|v^\star - x\|\leq \|x\|$, but I didn't ask that. (removed some inaccurate/outdated comments)
Additional facts found later, and a conjecture (23 may 2024):
In general we can always prove $||v^\star||\leq 2||x||$.
To see this, note that the projection of $x$ to a subspace is in the intersection of that subspace with the smallest ball centered at $x$ that intersects it (a "tangent" ball if you wish, with possibly higher cardinality tangent set). Then the projection to any subspace, is contained into the ball $B_x:=B_{||\cdot||}(x, ||x||)=\{y:\ ||x-y||\leq ||x||\}$ because $B_x$ intersects any vector subspace. Then, it is easy to see that $B_{||\cdot||}(x,||x||)\subseteq B_{||\cdot||}(0,2||x||)$ by triangle inequality, as desired.
Thus, for any norm there exists a constant $1\leq C\geq 2$ such that any projection $v^\star$ of a point $x$ onto a subspace satisfies $||v^\star||\leq C||x||$.
Furthermore, it is easy to see that Pythagoras theorem allows to show $C=1$ for Hilbert norms.
One can show that can't do better than $C=2$ for $\ell_1, \ell_\infty$ (take $x=e_1$ in the first case, and $x=(1,\dots, 1)$ in the second case, and $V$ approaching a facet of the ball $B_{||\cdot||}(x,||x||)$ from the inside).
Open questions:
1. One can conjecture that Hilbert norms are the only ones for which $C=1$ and the unit ball is strictly convex and $C^2$, in $2$-dimensional spaces at least.
2. We have $C=1$ in 2D for the norms which coincide with $\ell_p,\ell_q$ on alternating quadrants, with $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$ (from fedja's comment). Are there other 2D examples?
3. I don't know how to characterize cases in which $C=2$.
Please if you put a downvote, kindly explain why, so that I understand my own errors?

@MikhailKatz In the Euclidean case, yes, but consider projecting $(1,1)$ to the line spanned by $(2,1)$ under the norm $\max(|x|,|y|)$ and you will see that the life is not as simple as you suggest.

Sorry, this MikhailKatz must have removed their comment, what did the comment say?.. the max norm is not such norm, euclidean one is such norm, so what's a good property that separates the two?

taking v=0 shows that $||v^\star - x||\leq ||x||$, which is not what I asked, but I donkt know MikhailKatz' comment so this may be off track

I want that at least one of them works, so in that case it would be accepted. But if you take a line of slope 1/2 you get a counterexample for $\ell_1$.. see edited post.

I'm curious if you (or anyone) know an example of a non-Euclidean norm with this property in dimension 3 or higher.

@fedja I think that if Euclidean unit ball has as boundary a perfect sphere, then a small perturbation of this ball within the class of convex centrally symmetric bodies, will still have the desired norm-decreasing property from the question.. I did not try to prove it in detail though

Ok my previous comment about perturbations looks fishy, but the following one is more robust: a norm coming from an inner product will satisfy the property, because the property is valid for the Euclidean norm, and it is invariant under changing the norm unit ball by (invertible) linear deformations. Currently I tend to conjecture that this covers all $C^2$-regular norms in $\mathbb R^2$ (so, if property holds in 2D and the norm is $C^2$, then the unit ball is an ellipse)

@fedja I think that in 2D if I take the norm whose unit ball is a regular hexagon, then the property is valid

Correct. In 2D there are other examples too like $\ell^p$ norm in the first and the third quadrant and $\ell^q$ norm in the second and the third one ($\frac 1p+\frac 1q=1$), the hexagon corresponding to $p=1,q=\infty$. However I don't know anything like that in $\mathbb R^n$ for $n\ge 3$.

@fedja I think that in $\mathbb R^4$ the vertices of the regular $24$-cell are the analogues of the hexagon in $\mathbb R^2$ (vertices are $(\pm1, \pm1,0,0)$ and their permutations). It's harder to check but I think that the same proof that works for the regular hexagon in $\mathbb R^2$ might work also for this polytope.
